# node-configモジュールで設定を変更したら自動で読み込む機能を使いたい

Tags: node.js

node-configモジュールには、設定ファイルを書き換えたら自動でそれを読んで反映する機能があるようですが、どのようにすれば使えるようになるのかわかりません。
詳しい方がいましたらご教授ください。

こちらの記事を読むと、
http://memo.sugyan.com/entry/20110731/1312045169

watchForConfigFileChanges()を呼ぶと可能と書かれていますが、使おうとするとそのメソッドは定義されていないとエラーがでます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

使用されているモジュールは以下で宜しいでしょうか？

configモジュール
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

サイトのwikiを読むと
**「Updating configurations at runtime is no longer supported.」**
とあるので、今は実行中の構成の自動更新はやってないように見えます。
https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Upgrading-From-Config-0.x

さらに、
**「If you relied on the ability to alter configurations at runtime, you will have to replace that with a different implementation, or continue using the 0.4.x release branch. 」**
とも書いてあるので、どうしても使いたかったらv0.4.x系のものか、他のモジュールを探す必要がありそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。GitHubのソースも読みましたが、該当の関数が削除されていました。
今はできないようですね。